# Can jQuery modify the CSS for a specific media type?

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

Is it possible for jQuery to modify the CSS for a specific media type (e.g. print)?

My specific problem is that I'm using animate on an element and it's overriding the print stylesheet, which ruins my print layout. Though my problem is slightly different than the general question posed, I think an answer should help me resolve my problem. Any possible workarounds would be helpful also. Much obliged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do this with Javascript. Just use the `@media` rule in your css document. 
You can write all these stuff in only one css file. Here is the specific [W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

```
@media screen {

/* all your fancy screen css with a bunch of animation stuff*/

}

@media print {

/* all your fancy print css just plain */

}
```

You can write very specific declarations and match all elements to your needs. Btw it's supported **down to IE6**. Works like a charm in our projects.

```
@media print {
   body { font-size: 10pt }
}

@media screen {
   body { font-size: 13px }
}

@media screen, print {
   body { line-height: 1.2 }
}
```

Comment: Don't think this quite address my problem. Lets say I setup the stylesheet as you suggested. Say I specified different widths for print and screen. After the page displays, I use the jquery $(div).animate({width: 100px} to change the width. Now when I have the browser print, it'll use the new "100px" width instead of the print width. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is the right adress for your problem :) jQuery writes the width as inline-style (…style="width:100px"…). Inline Styles are higher in specifity. This is why your browser works with the inline width to print your document. You only have to override (http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) the inline style width. And in fact you should set with for your print style within `@media print`.

Comment: What if I want to change some style of div for specified media type during runtime, eg with using js. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Add a css for your media (print) with a specific rule that hides an element (eg #div { display: none; })

In your script, if this :

```
$('#div').is(':visible')
```

is true, then your are on a print media (printing).

Comment: Clever approach. Good thinking, Julien.

Comment: I don't think this will work, at least not when you have a loaded page on which you hit the print button. The problem is that the dom won't be reloaded and so this check isn't executed.

You could use `window.matchMedia('print')` and listen for media changes but it isn't very reliable.

Comment: It does work (tested) on IE8+, Chrome & FFox. BTW, it doesn't needs a DOM reload as it's a jQuery extension (the :visible pseudo) and pure Javascript.