# How do I use jQuery to retract dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer" when the media=print?

Tags: jquery, dojo, media, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

So I use the following code to create a TabContainer with 3 tabs. However, when I print the page, I would like the page to look as if there is no call to  dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer". What should I do to achieve this?

```
<div id="holdtabscript">
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>
</div>

<div dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="tabfunct">
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="pane1" selected="selected"> content1</div>
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="pane2"> content2</div>
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="pane3"> contents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927025/can-jquery-modify-the-css-for-a-specific-media-type

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using CSS to do it, if you have access to the page content.  Include a print stylesheet that hides the div...

In the head...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" tyle="text/css" media="print" href="print-stylesheet.css">
```

The css...

```
#tabfunct { display: none; }
```

Much easier than using javascript for something like this.

Comment: But I cannot get rid of the div by using CSS. I'm not trying to hide the div, but trying to remove the attr dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer" of that div.

Comment: You need to edit your question then, because it says "How do I use jQuery to remove the following div when the media is print" and all 3 posters have now answered that question.

Comment: Edited. Apologize for being vague.

Comment: No worries mate - it's your loss if you ask the question badly.  I just want you to get the help you need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
      #tabfunct  { display:none }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to hide the div, but trying to remove the attr dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer" of that div.

Comment: Thanks @powtac - I've not seen that method before.  I've only used the one I posted.  Yours is much nicer for small changes.  (I'm not gonna vote it up though, because the poster has asked the wrong question so both our answers are actually wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following library: http://cssmedia.pemor.pl/

Then just:

```
$(function() {
   if(IsMediaType('print') > 0) {
      $('#tabfunct').removeAttr('dojotype');
   }
});
```

Should probably do the trick.